# How to differentiate explicit null from omitted parameter

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to achieve something like this, basically differentiate from omitted parameter from explicitly set as `null`:

```
sealed class Expr
data class HasValue<out T>(val value: T)
object IsNull: Expr()

/* inside a class */
fun filter(v1: Expr<Int>? = null, v2: Expr<String>? = null): Collection<T> {
    when (v1) {
        is HasValue -> /* Filter collection elements that have some attr set to given value */
        is IsNull -> /* filter collection elements that have some attr set to null */
        is null -> /* do nothing, return all elements */
    }

    when (v2) /* so on */
}

/* call site */
myObj.filter(v1=IsNull<Int>(), v2=HasValue<String>("string"))
```

**EDIT:**

Working solution:

```
sealed class Expr<out T> {
    abstract val value: T?
}
data class WithValue<out T>(override val value: T?) : Expr<T>()

/* usage */
fun filter(v1: Expr<Int>? = null) {
    when (v1) {
        is WithValue -> println(if ((v1.value ?: 0) > 10) "10 and above" else "less") /* Type safe, explicit null handling */
        null -> println("isNull") /* parameter was omitted */
    }
}
filter(WithValue<Int>(null)) /* will match explicit null elements */
filter() /* will ignore v1 from filtering */
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you get some examples?

Comment: You want what you've shown, but without the help of the `Expr` type. Right?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I want to achieve similar behaviour, the example code doesn't compile

Comment: Your question misses that entire part, the problem statement. From all I can see, you're fine with the code you have.

Comment: Yeah if it only compile :)

Comment: Your problem is not "how to differentiate null from omitted parameter" -- you got that part sorted out already. Your problem is adjusting this to make it compile. So you're entirely missing the actual problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with provided code, mainly with generics. But I think that what was your main point of the questions was **exhaustive `when`**. If you want to match by type you write

- `is SomeClass` for classes
- `Object` for objects
- `null` for null

So your `when` should look like this:

```
when (v1) {
    is HasValue<*> -> /* Filter collection elements that have some attr set to given value */
    IsNull -> /* filter collection elements that have some attr set to null */
    null -> /* do nothing, return all elements */
}
```

and the whole code:

```
sealed class Expr {
    data class HasValue<out T>(val value: T) : Expr()
    object IsNull: Expr()
}

private fun <T> filter(v1: Expr? = null, v2: Expr? = null): Collection<T> {
    when (v1) {
        is HasValue<*> -> /* Filter collection elements that have some attr set to given value */
        IsNull -> /* filter collection elements that have some attr set to null */
        null -> /* do nothing, return all elements */
    }
    // matching with v2
}

/* call site */
filter<Int>(v1=IsNull, v2=HasValue("string"))
```

Comment: Thanks! that led me to what I wanted to achieve, see edited question

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it, not using `null`, but a custom private instance like:

```
/* inside a class */
private val EMPTY = Expr()
fun filter(v1: Expr<Int>? = EMPTY, v2: Expr<String>? = EMPTY): Collection<T> {
    if (v1 === EMPTY) {
        // parameter not defined by user
    } else {
        // parameter defined by user
    }
}
```